# Bit Mask usage in the program below from Programming Pearls

Tags: c, mask, bit, programming-pearls

I started reading "Programming Pearls" today and while doing it's exercise I came across this question "How would you implement your own bit vector?". When I looked at the solution it was like this:

```
#define BITSPERWORD 32
#define SHIFT 5
#define MASK 0x1F
#define N 10000000

int a[1 + N/BITSPERWORD]; 

void set(int i) { a[i >> SHIFT] |= (1 << (i & MASK));
```

Where I am getting confused at is this statement

```
 1 << (i & MASK)
```

Could someone please explain me what's going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `MASK` is set such that it has the lowest `SHIFT` bits set, where `SHIFT` is exactly the base-2 logarithm of `BITSPERWORD`.

Therefore `(i & MASK)` will select the lowest 5 bits of `i`, which is the same as taking the remainder after dividing by 32 (just consider how taking the lowest two digits of a decimal number gives you the remainder after dividing by 100, for example). That gives the number of the bit *within* a word we're interested in.

`1 << (i & MASK))` (which is, by the way, an *expression*, not a *statement*) now creates a value where exactly the bit we're interested in is set. Merging this value into the memory word with `|=` will set the desired bit of the bit vector.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Henning. Would this be valid if I then replace `(i & MASK)` with `(i % 32)`? If it will be valid but not elegant then could you please shed some light on why `i & MASK` is preferred over `i % 32`? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes -- `i & MASK` and `i % 32` are the same thing as long as you're sure `i` is not negative. The bitwise AND is typically more efficient than a division with remainder, and has therefore become the traditional choice. Or at least it _used to_ be more efficient back when compilers where stupid. Today you can expect even a moderately optimizing compiler to rewrite `i % 32` to `i & 31` internally in this context (either it can prove that `i` is not negative, in which case the rewriting is always safe, or it can reason that a negative result would trigger undefined behavior in the shift anyway).

Answer (score 2):

0x20 is 32, so `i & 0x1F` takes `i` modulo 32, so that you never shift by 32 bits. This is a safeguard because shifting by anything that isn't strictly less than the size of the type is undefined behaviour.